# What is the path of OAT file in Android 5.0

Tags: android

Android 5.0 uses dex2oat  to convert dex file to oat file when app installing.But in can only find boot.oat on my phone,where is the exactly path of convrted oat file?I want to have one for investigation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I find the answer by the doc below.

```
Dex2oat     
–   Ex: 
/system/bin/dex2oat --zip-fd=6 --zip-location=/system/app/
Email.apk --oat-fd=7 --oat-location=/data/dalvik-cache/
system@app@Email.apk@classes.dex --profile-file=/data/
dalvik-cache/profiles/com.android.email
Result  OAT file    will    be  placed  in  /data/dalvikcache
```

http://bofh.nikhef.nl/events/HitB/hitb-2014-amsterdam/praatjes/D1T2-State-of-the-Art-Exploring-the-New-Android-KitKat-Runtime.pdf

Comment: Short: `/data/dalvik-cache/<ARCH>/data@app@com.my.application-1@base.apk@classes.dex`

Comment: In case anyone else wonders like me, some (these) .dex files are actually oat files, and some .odex files are also oat files. You can see that by running `readelf -e file.dex` (on your machine not android) and looking for the .rodata and .text headers. This presentation was helpful http://newandroidbook.com/files/Andevcon-ART.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Found this reference on how to use `dex2aot` tool in NDK:
(`ndk/22.0.6917172/simpleperf/doc/scripts_reference.md`)

`/system/bin/dex2oat --dex-file=/data/local/tmp/app-profiling.apk --oat-file=/data/local/tmp/a.oat`

It worked for me on a rooted device running Android 11, as `/system/bin/dex2oat` is not accessible otherwise.